# meteor login dropdown drops below end of page

Tags: meteor, authentication, nav

I'm using meteor + bootstrap.
My nav is at the bottom of the page and the logginButtons are in the navbar.
The dropdown drops down, below the end of the page.
Is there a way to make it drop up, on **top** of the navbar ?
The pattern is my background, under firefox's window.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Bootstrap document](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) states it clearly that

> Dropdown menus can be changed to expand upwards (instead of downwards) by adding .dropup to the parent.

You will see a working example if you follow the link.

Comment: i'm not sure that meteor's loginButtons template is made on bootstrap, if so where should I add the class ?